# Method to execute stored procedure and return datatable in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, stored-procedures, datatable

I have some VB code like

```
  Dim data As DataTable = DataAccess.ExecuteDataSet("AuthenticateWebServiceClient" _
                                                , New SqlParameter("@ClientID", ClientId) _
                                                , New SqlParameter("@Password", Password) _
                                                , New SqlParameter("@WebServiceID", WebServiceID)).Tables(0)
```

And a DataAccess class with this function

```
 Public Shared Function ExecuteDataSet(ByVal storedProcName As String, ByVal ParamArray parameters As SqlParameter()) As DataSet
        'Try
        Dim command As SqlCommand = PrepareSPCommand(storedProcName, parameters)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        Return ds
        'Catch ex As Exception
        'ex.ToString()
        'End Try
    End Function
```

When I try to convert this to C# through a converter I get

```
private DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string storedProcName, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
   SqlCommand command = PrepareSPCommand(storedProcName, parameters);
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   adapter.Fill(ds);
   return ds;
}
```

Except PrepareSPCommand isn't recognized by VS. Does anyone know the correct way to convert this function to C#.

Comment: I think DataAccess.ExecuteDataSet is Method in Data Access Application Blocks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649538.aspx

Comment: Is that DataAccess a custom Data Access Layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
public SqlCommand PrepareSPCommand(string storedProcName, SqlParameter[] parameters, string connectionString){
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName,new SqlConnection(connectionString));
    command.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

    return command;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  There's nothing mythical about C# compared to VB.net

```
DataTable data = DataAccess.ExecuteDataSet("AuthenticateWebServiceClient", New SqlParameter("..."), etc).Tables[0];
```